# How do I size my map in blender so it will be the right size in unity?

Tags: unity, blender

I am working on a fps game but I cant get the size right of my map in blender, every time I export it to a .fbx file (unity won't work if it is a .blend file) it is a super small plane floor in unity the player controller is 10 as big as the map.
I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Scaling in Inspector]

When you import an FBX file in Unity, it is scaled to 0.01 of its original size. You can either put it back to 1 (or anything you want) in the Model tab of the Inspector every time you import something, or [you can make a small script](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/30408/how-can-i-change-the-scale-size-of-the-fbx-importe.html#answer-30423) that will do that for you whenever you import an asset.

Answer (score 0):

Either change its `scale` from the Inspector after selecting the game object or the `pixels per unit` value of the exported asset from Import Settings (the menu when you choose the exported asset in the project hierarchy).

Answer (score 0):

All you need to to is just remember one rule of thumb.Although I couldn't find any documentation on this.But with little workout I found that for Cube,Cylinder and Sphere[*]

> 50 Blender units  = 1 Unity unit

So You can do either of these:

1.Scale Your Objects 50x in Blender "Just" before exporting (By Hitting `S` and then 50,which will uni formally scale your Object 50 times in all axes).

2.Or Import Your Objects in Unity as it is, and in Transform Panel -> Scale, Change every Value to 50.

[*] These Standard Primitives in both Programs spawn with equal Dimensions.But a Plane Does not(It is Larger in Unity)